# Is there anyway to use try/catch in troposphere?

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, troposphere, sceptre

I'm using sceptre user data and I can't use AWS::NoValue with it. Since I don't want to change the current template much, I want to do a workaround but I see a warning in try line, which is `Expected expression Pylance`. How can I use try catch in this case? If I can't, is there any workaround this?

```
                LifecycleRule(
                    Id="Xxxx",
                    Status="Enabled",
                    ExpirationInDays=
                        try:
                            bucket['ExpirationInDays'] 
                        except KeyError: Ref("AWS::NoValue")
                ),
            ]),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this fragment work for you:

```
LifecycleRule(Id="Xxxx", Status="Enabled",
ExpirationInDays=bucket.get('ExpirationInDays', Ref('AWS::NoValue'))
```

I'm assuming *bucket* is a Python dictionary. Using a dictionary's get() function like this avoids the need for a try/except construct

Comment: I got this error.=:
`  File "/usr/src/app/xxxx/s3.py", line 104, in create_s3_bucket
    ExpirationInDays= bucket['ExpirationInDays']
KeyError: 'ExpirationInDays'` Actually this dictionary is being created by sceptre. And there are some keys don't have `ExpirationInDays` variable in it, so I want to replace it with `Ref('AWS::NoValue')` in this case. This is doc for [sceptre](https://sceptre.cloudreach.com/dev/docs/stack_config.html#examples)

Comment: The code I have offered will **not** cause a KeyError Exception. That's the whole point of using the the *get()* function with a default value

Comment: Sorry about the false alarm, the file wasn't saved. :) Thanks very much!